# HGLRC OpenGL rendering context - How to indicate the version of the OpenGL

Tags: windows, opengl, graphics, rendering, hwnd

How I'm creating my rendering context using wgl :

```
//Device
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

HGLRC hRC = wglCreateContext(hdc);
```

How/where/when should I change the version of the OpenGL context?

Is there a function like wglCreateContextVer(hdc, major(3) /*major*/, 0 /*minor*/, "core");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wglCreateContextAttribsARB`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/WGL_ARB_create_context.txt). e.g.:

```cpp
int attributes[] = {
    WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
    WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
    WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
    WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB, 1,
    0,
};
HGLRC hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hdc, 0, attributes);
```

See also [Sample code showing how to create a window using a modern OpenGL core profile context without any libraries other than the standard Win32 wglXXX calls.](https://gist.github.com/nickrolfe/1127313ed1dbf80254b614a721b3ee9c)

Comment: @LucasSokol What does this have to do with glew? See https://gist.github.com/nickrolfe/1127313ed1dbf80254b614a721b3ee9c

Answer (score 2):

The cliff notes version:

1. Create dummy window and OpenGL context to get access to extension functions.
2. Fetch entry points for `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` and friends.
3. Use those to create the window proper and the OpenGL context for it.
4. Bonus points: Making it all thread safe.

For everyone's convenience I did all the heavy lifting in my `wglarb` helper library. Get it here (also comes with example programs): https://git.datenwolf.net/wglarb/